# Connect Credit card reader

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to develop application like this :
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paypodd/id341546114?mt=8

I am going to develop one application for credit card reader but i have no idea for connect external device to iPhone. right now i am using ExternalAccessory Class for find connected device but i am not getting any event after connect any Accessory to my iPhone

if anyone has developed this kind of application please provide me the flow 
i am really confused..

[image: My Card reader is like this]

Thanks .!

Answer (score 5):

Do you plan on producing your own credit card reader for the iPhone/iPod? If so, you will probably need to go through Apple's "Made For iPod" (MFi) program. See: http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

If not, your options for connecting the reader to the iOS device are limited. You **cannot** connect generic USB or Bluetooth devices -- one of the few devices I'm aware of which gets around this is the Square reader, which is a custom hardware device which communicates over the audio jack. Setting this up likely involved a lot of custom audio engineering on Square's part; it is **not** an easy task, nor is it something that can be done with off-the-shelf parts.

If you have other plans for what type of reader to use, please add details to your question!

Comment: First of Thanks for replying me.

Comment: First of thanks for Replying me. Actually i want to develop the one demo application which read the information from card-reader and one note one thing The process by which a chip card is read is defined by EMV standards.\

Comment: iOS devices do not have any hardware capable of reading an EMV chip. You will need to use (and, most likely, design/build) a reader to interface with the chip.

Comment: Actually ... Our hardware developer has create one device for reading EMV chip... but problem is there i am not getting that device connected or disconnected notifications ... and until now i had never worked with hardware communications with iPhone so  if you have any idea please help me.

Comment: @duskwuff: thanks a lot i wiil get an idea from ur answer as i am looking for the answer of the same problem........!

Comment: Thanks for sharing above information. Sweeta, can you get any solution for  read credit-card  info using card reader? if you get any solution then please share that , so that help for other peoples. Thanks.